# Android Config in Eclipse - SDK Preferences wants ...\Platforms, but SDK doesn't come with one

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I'm installing and configuring Eclipse Galileo 3.52 on a PC following the instructions on [Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

All the steps in "Downloading the ADT Plugin" go fine with no errors.   But when I get to the next step "Configuring the ADT Plugin" it fails when I set my SDK location, saying that it can't find android-sdk-windows\platforms.

But no kidding - I'm using the android-sdk_r06-windows SDK and the Readme file says, "*The Android SDK archive now only contains the tools. It no longer comes populated with a specific Android platform or Google add-on. Instead you
use the SDK Manager to install or update SDK components such as platforms,
tools, add-ons, and documentation.*"   How how I do this?  Do I have to use an older version of the SDK to go with this older version of Eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

---

**To QRohlf:**

I tried that. I ran it from the command line and got the same error:

[INFO] Starting Android SDK and AVD Manager

Error: Error parsing the sdk.

Error: `C:\Documents and Settings\Peter\My Documents\SW\AndroidSDK\android-sdk-windows\platforms` is missing.

Error: Unable to parse SDK content.

"platforms" is missing because it's not included in this version of the SDK. It says so in the Readme file. I'm trying to follow the instructions in the link in the original post which imply this can be all done from the IDE but I don't know what step is supposed to create the platforms folder.

It's tempting to manually create the folder but I want to do this 'by the book' as the Eclipse/Android team intended because I'm making a 'getting started' guide for some students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redid my installation from scratch but this time I put the SDK higher in the file system - C:\SDKs\AndroidSDK....  and this time it was happy.

I don't know if it was having a problem with the long pathname or the space between "My" and "Documents" or what, but the issue is now resolved.

Comment: Yes...you are not supposed to have spaces in your folder structure and if so..., it screwws...It happened to me as well and was a nightmare to get rid of that silly issue and I believe this we can learn only by burning our fingers... :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the Sdk Setup.exe in android-sdk_r06-windows and install the addons. See [Adding SDK Components](http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html) for detailed instructions.