# Does Android have a "known issues" list?

Tags: android

I'm a newbie Android developer and I'm also in the market for a new phone, so I spent all last week doing side-by-side comparisons between various Verizon 'droids with my wife's iPhone.  We found a lot of problems.  One problem was on 2 different manufacturers' phones running 2.2, but it does NOT occur on my Android emulator in Eclipse running 2.2!

**MY Question:**  Does Google have a searchable list of known issues (and workarounds and statuses) similar to Microsoft's Knowledge Base (the famous KB's) ?

**N.B.**  I'm **not** asking for a list of bugs people have encountered -  I can find that by Googling - Microsoft's KB articles are issues that the company has acknowledged and they often include workarounds or other useful information.

Comment: In stack Overflow terms what is an "answer"?    If I post a question and someone posts a response is that an "answer"?   This question is a good example.  I said I was looking for the equivalent of KB (where the company acknowledges the issue and has a workaround) articles, not just a bugs list.   I don't have that yet but maybe there really is one and no one here knows about it or has responded yet.   I'll start a new thread about this.

Comment: @Roger Pate - It was 0% when I made that comment. I consider that low.

Comment: @Roger Pate - So, what's the solution? I disagree with his analysis that his questions did not have answers - almost all of them did. What I did not check was how long they had been alive - a good handful were created only over the last few days, so it's perhaps admissable that they haven't been checked yet. Should we be encouraging new SO users to just ask a question, take an answer and totally disregard the answerer? I'm not adverse to just having a "thank you comment" system, but he didnt even acknowledge his answerer's existence.

Comment: I do apologise to the OP if he feels "dinged". But I feel that it's only polite to at least *acknowledge the existence* of the people who are trying to help you. In terms of sources, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614535/target-specific-emulators-for-eclipse-in-android) has a great answer as far as I can see, no tick, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531348/commercial-ideemulator-for-android) has a reasonable answer given the nature of the question, no tick,...

Comment: ..., [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514985/android-config-in-eclipse-sdk-preferences-wants-platforms-but-sdk-doesnt) had an answer which was completely ignored - no show it was even tried - in favour of the OP posting his own answer days later. Out of all of his questions, I found *one* that didn't have any decent answer, and maybe another one that had a half-good-half-bad answer.

Comment: @Stephen: Instead of 3 long comments here, you'd have a better impact answering on the Meta question I linked; and I'd be happy to comment on your answer there.

Comment: @Roger Pate - That would indeed be the preferable solution. I've bookmarked this page and will return and extract my comments later once I'm home. I feel my above comments may have been overly harsh; I think I need some time to calm myself to the point where I can answer with what I think rather than what I feel. Thank you for your attitude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official bugtracker: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

They mainly have work arounds, too. Famous one: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=979

Comment: This is only the list of official bugs and issues in the android core code. If a manufacturer made an error in customizing android to their hardware and needs this won't be visible in the issue list.

Comment: thats true, but he asked for the "google list" any other way is to search for a developer forum and search there for issues other devs have found...

Answer (score 3):

yes we do have a bug tracker for android. You can access it here

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: As I responded above to Warren, this doesn't seem to be equivalent to to Microsoft's KB articles.   But Android has a much more open-sourcey kind of flavor so maybe it's as close as I'm gonna get.    So I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: It won't let me mark them both as answered even though technically they're the same answer so I have to give it to Warren 'cause he did it first.  But I clicked the up-arrow, whatever that means.   StackOverflow is arcane.

Comment: @Peter Nelson - It's not arcane. It's merely a question/answer system. You ask a question, then hopefully you get a (good) answer. If you get an answer that perfectly answers your question, you give it the tick. If an answer doesn't perfectly answer it but brings up a good point, or is too late, it's quite common to upvote it. A ticked answer gives the answerer 15 points (and yourself a couple too - 2 iirc). An upvoted answer gives the answerer 10 points (but none to yourself). An important difference is that only the asker can mark an answer as ticked, but anyone can upvote it.